# Remove Thread.sleep() in case of Sending Message to ActiveMQ

Tags: sonarqube, activemq-classic

I was fixing sonar lint error in my project. I have seen a block of Code where sonar lint is giving me error of rule `squid:S2276` to replace Thread.sleep(100); with wait(). But wait() should be in conditional loop to escape spurious wakeup problem. But I am not getting such a condition how I should use.

Can i achieve the same thing without sleep()

```
public class ACTOOBEventSubSMSProducer {

private ACTOOBEventSubSMSProducer(){
    super();
}
private static Logger logger = LoggerManager.getInstance().getCoreProcessingLogger();
public static final String CONNECTION_FACTORY = "java:jboss/activemq/ConnectionFactory";
static final String QUEUE_NAME = "java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/actOOBEventSubscriptionSMS";
static ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = null;
static Connection connection = null;
static Session session = null;
static Destination destination = null;
static MessageProducer messageProducer = null;

static {
    connectionFactory = ServiceLocator.getJmsConnectionFactory(CONNECTION_FACTORY);
    try {
        connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.DUPS_OK_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        destination = ServiceLocator.getJmsDestination(QUEUE_NAME);
        messageProducer = session.createProducer(destination);
        messageProducer.setDisableMessageID(true);
        messageProducer.setDisableMessageTimestamp(true);
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        logger.error("Error in creating ConnectionFactory",e);
    }
}

/**
 * This method sends OOB Event SMS Message in Queue.
 * 
 * @param message
 */
public static synchronized void sendMessage(Serializable payload) throws JmsProducerException {
    try {
        ObjectMessage message = session.createObjectMessage(payload);
        messageProducer.send(message, javax.jms.DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT, javax.jms.Message.DEFAULT_PRIORITY,
                1800000);
    } catch (JMSException je) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
            ObjectMessage message = session.createObjectMessage(payload);
            messageProducer.send(message, javax.jms.DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT, javax.jms.Message.DEFAULT_PRIORITY,
                    1800000);
        } catch (JMSException jee) {
            logger.error("Error in sendMessage()",jee);
            throw new JmsProducerException(jee);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            logger.error("Error in sendMessage()",ie);
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            throw new JmsProducerException(ie);
        }
    } catch (ServiceLocatorException sle) {
        logger.error("Error in sendMessage()",sle);
        throw new JmsProducerException(sle);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

A carefully crafted for loop with the iterations count being the number of times you wanted to retry and some exception handling logic to break the loop if things work would do the trick in at a slightly clearer manner perhaps, otherwise using a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor or or Timer would be an option.

Comment: Thank you for taking out your precious time. Can you share a snippet code?